# List of addons/extensions for gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

**This list is now more or less superceded by https://extensions.gnome.org/ where extensions can be one click installed and configured.**

There are several addons for gnome-shell. Please help me compile a list of existiong addons

I have answered my question by adding the extensions I know of as answers. Since there are many extensions each single answers is still a stub.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BVuOTNkYYk&feature=player_embedded)'s a video of some of the extensions in action:

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extension

Comment: Please keep in mind that list questions are generally not allowed on Ask Ubuntu. See the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask) for details.

Comment: Ah I didn't know. They seem to be quite successful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there's the alpha of [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) where you can get some more extensions. Hopefully in the future this will make this community wiki obsolete :P

Answer (score 2):

### [**alternative-status-menu**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

For those who want a power off item visible at all the time.

Comment: I was and am still speachless that someone thinks just having a "suspend" option is a good idea. Seriously. Unbelievable! Who ever is responsible for that decision should be beaten to death with his own shoe.

Answer (score 2):

### [**user-theme**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Loads a shell theme

Answer (score 2):

### [**weather extension**](https://github.com/simon04/gnome-shell-extension-weather)

shows the weather right next to the clock.

[image: picture]
 For installation instrucions check [here](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/webupd8/~3/PP3SvsidyS8/gnome-shell-weather-extension.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is the most exhaustive list: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions

If you're feeling adventurous, you could always try to create your own. Useful guide here: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/04/gnome-3-shell-extensions.html

Comment: Those are exactly the same ones as on webupd8.

Comment: @turbo You're right, I didn't realize. At least the gnome.org link is the official list of them. I found a couple more in the [gnome-shell-extensions git repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/), _drive-menu_ and _places-menu_.

Comment: Description for drive-menu: A status menu for accessing and unmounting removable devices.

Answer (score 1):

### [**windowsNavigator**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Allow keyboard selection of windows and workspaces in overlay mode

Answer (score 0):

### [**alternate-tab**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Lets you use classic Alt+Tab

Answer (score 0):

### [**auto-move-windows**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Lets you manage your workspaces more easily, assigning a specific workspace to each application

Answer (score 0):

### [**dock**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Shows a dock-style task switcher on the right side of the screen
Lets you manage your workspaces more easily, assigning a specific workspace to each application

Answer (score 0):

### [**gajim**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Integration with Gajim

Answer (score 0):

### [**xrandr-indicator**](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions)

Replace the GTK+ based indicator from gnome-settings-daemon with a native one

Answer (score 0):

### [**drive-menu**](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/)

A status menu for accessing and unmounting removable devices

Answer (score 0):

### [**places-menu**](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/)

Shows a status Indicator for navigating to Places

Answer (score 0):

### [**gnome2-like desktop**](http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/extensions/index.html)

A GNOME2-like desktop. Videos and Photos on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/new-gnome-shell-extensions-that-provide.html). It's also possible to install the bottom panel [only](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/bottom-panel-gnome2-like-panel-gnome.html)

Answer (score 0):

### [**window-overlay-icons**](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extensions-sustmi)

Display overlay icons in window overview. This git repo also has another extension to navigate history with the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude for creating and maintaining the post. Useful for everyone :)

Few more

Media player extension

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/try-new-mint-gnome-shell-extensions.html

Pidgin Integration

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/native-gnome-shell-notifications-for.html

Thunderbird extension

https://github.com/tanwald/gnome-shell-extension-thunderbird-integration

Workspace Switcher Extension,Alternative Status Menu GNOME Shell Extension,SystemMonitor GNOME Shell Extension,Apps Menu GNOME Shell Extension,Places Menu GNOME Shell Extension,User-Theme GNOME Shell Extension,Alternate Tab GNOME Shell Extension

http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/10/7-best-gnome-shell-extensions-install.html

Many standard extensions can be easily installed thr ppa's

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html

I am sure some day we will have a chrome web store sort of thing for gnome shell extensions too , until then we have to live maintaining a list like these :P (or some one might have already created a better blog having the list)

Answer (score 0):

Still buggy but has to be mentioned: The [Mint GNOME3 Shell Extensions (MGSE)](https://github.com/linuxmint/MGSE). It's actually many different plugins like a xrandr extension, a new bottom-panel, a shutdown-menu etc. Those can be installed seperately see [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/try-new-mint-gnome-shell-extensions.html) (also from the webupd8 PPA).

Answer (score 0):

Intergrate google calendar into gnome-shell

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/google-calendar-gnome-shell-integration.html